# which one is more common between handshake and handclasp?

Tags: word-choice

Which on is more common phrase between handshake and handclasp? I looked it up on dictionary but I couldn't understand. And what's its preposition? For example I handshake with her? Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To shake hands is a formal business greeting.

To clasp hands implies a more intense event; a departing friend, consolation over someone's misfortune etc., or a particularly exuberant politician, greeting potential voters.

> I handshake with her

doesn't really work.

> I [shake]shook hands with her.
>
> We greeted each other with a simple handshake.

The 'act' is a handshake, it describes that you are shaking hands.

*Note:* in modern terminology - Computers handshake, people shake hands.

> The connection was set up using a handshake method.

Comment: We can also say, "We shook hands," which means, "We had a handshake."

Comment: thanks for your answers but I have a slight problem yet! So when I see a friend and take her/him hand as a greeting, I had a handshake with him/her? Or I had a handclaps? How about when we want ro say goodbye and take our hands and say goodbye?

Comment: You shook hands. Unless there was hugging involved, I doubt it would qualify as a clasp.